# Should you extinguish Chanukah candles that are still lit the next night?

Tags: blessing, chanuka, menora-chanukia, candle-lighting, fire-burning

If someone lit Chanukah candles with enough oil/wax to last more than 24 hours and now wants to light the same Hanukiah the next day with the original candle still burning what would the proper action be? Should this person:

1. Extinguish the candle and then relight it with a blessing?
2. Leave the candle as is and make the blessing over it
3. None of the above, but instead find an alternative way to light a different Hanukiah

Comment: There's also 4. Leave the candle as is and make no new blessing. That seems much more plausible than 2 or 3.

Comment: Since the light had been burning for such a long time it would be a good idea to make sure that before relighting with a bracha you have the needed minimum amount of oil/wax for it to burn for

Answer (score 4):

The Shulchan Aruch (OC 675:1) rules that since the mitzvah is to light the menorah, if it is still lit, it must be extinguished and then relit.

Comment: Seems a shame not to wait and see if it stays lit for 8 nights

Comment: @MosesSupposes see this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138837/can-should-one-undo-a-miracle

Comment: @MosesSupposes You still have to light a different candle.

Comment: @N.T. One fulfills their obligation with the lighting of one ner. Hamehader adds every night. Nevertheless, just one and the miswa is fulfilled. So why not leave the neroth that are already lit as they are and add one one more for the current night? This would not seem to violate the principle of hadlaqa 'oseh miswa

Comment: @N.T. I know - was just joking!